# how to work with PhpMyAdmin and Github

Tags: mysql, github, phpmyadmin

I just started using Github and I cant find how to import my database from PhpMyAdmin on Github?
after importing it ... is it automatically updated when i push the code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish.

MySQL is a database server; it holds data and can be used for concurrent access by many clients.

phpMyAdmin is a particular type of application that can access MySQL servers; it's particularly made so administrators can manage their database installations easier by adding users, modifying table structure, and so on. For end users to interact with your database, you'll want a custom application or web site, though; phpMyAdmin isn't designed for end user interaction.

Github is a software hosting platform that allows software developers to host downloads and development (including the source code, issue trackers, and other tools).

Since neither phpMyAdmin nor Github are things that "have" a database, asking how to import from one to the other doesn't make much sense. What exactly is it you're trying to accomplish?

**EDIT**

In order to ensure that all your contributors are using the same database schema, you have two choices: either your structure becomes the master version that they have to remove their database and import each time (simple, but destructive), or you can provide an upgrade path so that they import the base version and you provide incremental upgrades along the way as you change the structure (more complex, but it lets them keep their data).

To do the first (destructive) choice, you'll just do an export of your table structure (you can do that with the phpMyAdmin "Export" tab, selecting the Structure button). Then upload that .sql file to Github and your contributors can download it and import to their MySQL instances.

For the second one, there are a number of tools that can generate the differences for you, and I don't know any of them well enough in particular (aside from phpMyAdmin) to recommend any. What you're looking for, though, is a tool that will let you migrate database schema or provide version control for your database structure. Either of those should turn up some results, and the program will generate incremental SQL files as you make changes (which I imagine isn't that often anyway). So you'll post the original structure, then make a change (perhaps adding a timestamp column for "last modified"). You'll run your tool which will create a file that adds that timestamp. Your contributors can run that SQL file to modify their table structure. Then some time later you may wish to add another table, and the process repeats.

You can easily do that by hand with SQL statements as well; you don't need to rely on a tool for generating the differences.

What I, personally, do in this sort of situation is make the change on my development server, using the phpMyAdmin preview SQL feature to see the exact command that's going to run, then I copy and paste that in to a .sql file I make by hand which I import to the production server. That way, I have made no direct changes by hand to the production server; it's all in version control and reproducible. There are tools that would make it easier for me, but I do it so rarely that I just do it by hand.

Comment: First thank you
well what i exactly want do is that i want all my contributers on github to have the same database architecture (not necesserly thecontent)...because we need this to test the code that interact with the database that i created using phpmyadmin... I hope its clear now...excuse my english

Comment: I've edited my response with some thoughts. By the way, your English seems fine, but I think the question itself wasn't that clear because of all the technologies involved.